# Em um requisição Ajax XHR, no HTTP_ACCEPT qual significado de q=0.01?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, http-headers

Tenho uma comunicação via [Ajax (xhr)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), e no meu HEADER o valor do `HTTP_ACCEPT` é `application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01`.

Eu entendo todos os valores anteriores, gostaria de achar algo que me explique o **q=0.01** pois não consigo saber o significado ou que regra é essa. Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `q=` é o fator de "peso", ou seja é usado pra indicar a prioridade para o servidor (back-end), é importante notar que isto pode ser usado em outros headers além do `Accept` como por exemplo:

- `Accept-Charset`
- `Accept-Language`
- `Accept-Encoding`
- `TE`

O **`q=`** pode ser chamado de *Quality values* ou *q-values* ou *q-factors* e são usados para descrever a ordem de prioridade de valores em uma lista separados por vírgulas. A importância de um valor é marcada pelo sufixo `;q=` imediatamente seguido por um valor entre 0 e 1 incluído (0.0 até 1.0 por exemplo), com até três dígitos decimais, o valor mais alto que denota a prioridade mais alta e quando não está presente, o valor padrão é **1**. Conforme descrito em https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Quality_values

Exemplo:

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

Indicará a seguinte ordem de prioridade:

| Valor | Prioridade |
| --- | --- |
| `text/html` e `application/xhtml+xml` | 1.0 |
| `application/xml` | 0.9 |
| `*/*` | 0.8 |

Então isto o `Accept` indica quais tipos de `content-type` o navegador aceita e o `q=` irá definir a prioridade, no caso acima a requisição espera afirma para o back-end que aceita `text/html`, `application/xhtml+xml` e `application/xml`, mas prioriza os 2 primeiros, se disponível.

Note que o `*/*` provavelmente afirma que se não tiver o 3 primeiros na ordem de prioridade, então será aceito qualquer tipo, claro que isso é possível customizar no momento da requisição, um exemplo em com `XMLHttpRequest` (Ajax):

```js
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

//Defina como false
oReq.open("GET", "/url", true);

oReq.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

...

oReq.send(null);
```

Neste exemplo como não especifiquei o `q=` então será equivalente a dizer que `q=1` para `application/json`, no entanto isto tem que ser **resolvido** no back-end (leia no final aonde escrevi **extra**).

---

### Accept-Language

Um exemplo interessante de uso creio que para a maioria é com o `Accept-Language`, pois se o navegador ou uma requisição definir algo como:

```
Accept-Language: pt, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7
```

Você poderá resolver no lado do servidor para buscar por `pt`, se não encontrar a prioridade seria o *inglês britânico* e se ainda não disponivel este idioma para a página especifica irá ser exibido o *inglês* (`en;q=0.7`).

---

### Obtendo o valores no back-end:

Em C# existem diferentes namespaces para usos de diferentes tecnologias, então vou listar apenas as principais do `System.Net.Http.Headers`, o básico: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.stringwithqualityheadervalue?view=net-8.0

| Header | Propriedade | Valor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `Accept` | [`HttpRequestHeaders.Accept`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders.accept) | `HttpHeaderValueCollection<MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue>` |
| `Accept-Charset` | [`HttpRequestHeaders.AcceptCharset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders.acceptcharset) | `HttpHeaderValueCollection<StringWithQualityHeaderValue>` |
| `Accept-Encoding` | [`HttpRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders.acceptencoding) | `HttpHeaderValueCollection<StringWithQualityHeaderValue>` |
| `Accept-Language` | [`HttpRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders.acceptlanguage) | `HttpHeaderValueCollection<StringWithQualityHeaderValue>` |
| `TE` | [`HttpRequestHeaders.TE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders.te) | `HttpHeaderValueCollection<TransferCodingWithQualityHeaderValue>` |

Em Java existem diferentes frameworks, então cada um pode ter seu meio de tratar isso, mas em SpringBoot você pode tratar o com [`org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html):

- Accept: [`org.springframework.http.MediaType`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#getQualityValue()) (veja o método [`getQualityValue()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html#getQualityValue()))

Em PHP não existe um meio genérico para tratar cada tipo de header, no entanto para o `Accept-Language` existe a função especifica para tratar idiomas/línguas, a [`locale_accept_from_http()`](http://php.net/manual/en/locale.acceptfromhttp.php), que está disponivel desde o PHP5.3, exemplo de uso:

Exemplo procedural

```php
<?php
$locale = locale_accept_from_http('pt, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7');
var_dump($locale);
```

Método estático da classe:

```php
<?php
$locale = Locale::acceptFromHttp('pt, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7');
var_dump($locale);
```

Comment: Show Guilherme, obrigado!