# Carregar imagens webp

Tags: php, laravel, webp

Gostaria de fazer algo semelhante ao que faz o link a seguir com as imagens de meu site, utilizando o formato webp:

[exemplo neste site](http://shopfacil.vteximg.com.br/arquivos/ids/8043120-430-430/image-14d749d28e68b73ea65d4832318ba6d6.jpg?v=636408381268700000)

Quando tento salvar a imagem por esse link, pelo Chrome, ela salva no formato webp. Se eu tento salvar por outro navegador, ela salva no formato jpg. Se eu retiro da url a parte após o "?", salva no formato jpg em todos os navegadores.

Alguém sabe como é feito isso? Se é na hora do upload ou da exibição?

O site é feito em PHP, utilizando o framework Laravel.

Comment: suaimagem.jpg?v=123 Qual é o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Isso é feito durante a requisição. O código captura o parâmetro `v` (Ou o navegador verifica os cabeçalhos da requisição), verifica se a imagem está em *cache*, caso esteja retorna. Caso não esteja, você pode fazer da seguinte forma.

**No seu servidor *(Vou utilizar o `Nginx` para exemplo)***

```
# Aqui eu informo que toda imagem em `jpg` deverá ser redirecionada para o arquivo `image.jpg`
location ~ \.jpg$ {
    rewrite (.*) /image.php?$args last;
}
```

**No PHP:**

```
<?php

// Captura o nome da imagem que foi solicitada    
$request_uri = preg_replace("/^\/([^\?]*).*/", "$1", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// Abre a imagem no formato JPG
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($request_uri);

// Adiciona o Header informando o Content-Type
header("Content-Type: image/webp");

// Converte a imagem para WEBP
imagewebp($image);
```

> Isso acontece no *Chrome*, pois ele captura a extensão através do `Content-Type`.

[**Demonstração Temporária 1**](http://oc.rickcds.com/epica.jpg)
[**Demonstração Temporária 2**](http://oc.rickcds.com/epica.jpg?v=1)
[**Imagem Original**](http://crypticrock.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/epica-2017-interview.jpg)

Comment: Entendi Valdeir, muito obrigado mesmo. Vou tentar fazer aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Isto é feito usando [**Content negotiation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation) usando o header `Accept:`, como expliquei nesta resposta:

- [**Em um requisição Ajax XHR, no HTTP_ACCEPT qual significado de q=0.01?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260615/3635)

No Chrome, Opera e outros navegadores baseado em Chromium tem suporte para `webp` então o header é passado assim pelo navegador quando requisita a página:

```
GET /arquivos/ids/8043120-430-430/image-14d749d28e68b73ea65d4832318ba6d6.jpg?v=636408381268700000 HTTP/1.1
Host: shopfacil.vteximg.com.br
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36 OPR/51.0.2830.26
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
```

Mas quando acessa via Firefox por não ter suporte ao webp será acessado via assim provavelmente, veja que que no `Accept:` tem `image/webp`:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,**image/webp**,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
```

Já no **Firefox** o navegador requisita assim:

```
GET /arquivos/ids/8043120-430-430/image-14d749d28e68b73ea65d4832318ba6d6.jpg?v=636408381268700000 HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection:keep-alive
Host: shopfacil.vteximg.com.br
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
```

Claro que no PHP não tem nada nativo para o **q-factor**, mas existem libs via PEAR como

Ou então usar o script [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9943330/1518921) mas ajusta-lo para o cabeçalho `Accept:` (que é usado para mime-type), por exemplo:

```
function AcceptHeader($name)
{
    $qvalues = array(); // used to store values

    if (empty($_SERVER[$name]) === false) {
        $result = preg_match_all('/([a-z]{1,8}(-[a-z]{1,8})?)\s*(;\s*q\s*=\s*(1|0\.[0-9]+))?/i', $_SERVER[$name], $parsed);

        if ($result && count($parsed[1])) {
            $qvalues = array_combine($parsed[1], $parsed[4]);

            // Define o valor para tipos sem q-value definido
            foreach ($qvalues as &$val) {
                if ($val === '') {
                     $val = 1;
                }
            }

            // sort list based on value 
            arsort($qvalues, SORT_NUMERIC);
        }
    }

    return $qvalues;
}
```

Exemplo para pegar o header de tipo requisitado pelo navegador:

```
$tipos = AcceptHeader('HTTP_ACCEPT');
```

Exemplo para obter idiomas suportados pelo navegador:

```
$idiomas = AcceptHeader('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE');
```

Mas como o foco é o mime-type, então deve usar mais ou menos assim:

```
$tipos = AcceptHeader('HTTP_ACCEPT');

//Filtra somente imagens
$tipos = array_filter($tipos, function($header, $qvalue) {
    return stripos($header, 'image/') === 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

//Pega a primeira chave
$tipos = reset($tipos);
$tipo = key($tipos);

//Se contiver imagem/webp
if ($tipo == 'image/webp') {
     readfile('images/webp/image.webp');
} else {
     readfile('images/jpg/image.jpg');
}
```

Claro que pode ser bem mais simples ainda, isto tudo acima é apenas uma sugestão de como entregar conforme a preferencia do navegador ou usuário o tipo de conteúdo, mas você pode optar por decidir apenas checar se existe o suporte independente da prioridade do **q-factor** usando `preg_match` e **regex**, assim:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']) && preg_match('#[\s,;]image/webp[\s,;]#', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'])) {
     readfile('images/webp/image.webp');
} else {
     readfile('images/jpg/image.jpg');
}
```